# Why hibernate is getting wrong field name when I'm mapping?

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I'm getting this message:

```
Message: Invalid column name 'tftire_siteid'.
```

I have two classes:

```
class TFTire implements Serializable {

    static hasMany = [ propertyList : TFTireProperty ]

    static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'TF_TIRE'
        id composite:['siteID','idRec'], generator: "assigned"
```

And this one:

```
class TFTireProperty implements Serializable {

    TFTire tfTire
    static belongsTo = [ TFTire ]

     static mapping = {
        version false
        table 'TF_TireProperty'
        id composite:['siteID','idRec'], generator: "assigned"
```

My hibernate is querying like this:

```
Hibernate: 
select propertyli0_.**tftire_**siteid as tftire5_1_1_,
propertyli0_.**tftire_**id_rec as tftire6_1_1_, propertyli0_.SiteID as SiteID1_,
propertyli0_.IDRec as IDRec1_, propertyli0_.SiteID as SiteID0_0_,
propertyli0_.IDRec as IDRec0_0_, propertyli0_.FullName as FullName0_0_,
propertyli0_.ShortName as ShortName0_0_, propertyli0_.tftire_siteid as tftire5_0_0_,
propertyli0_.tftire_id_rec as tftire6_0_0_, propertyli0_.TP as TP0_0_
from TF_TireProperty propertyli0_
where propertyli0_.**tftire_siteid**=?
  and propertyli0_.**tftire_id_rec**=?
```

It was supposed to be only .siteid and idrec. Without the underlines and without the tftire name.

Comment: not sure why you use the static mapping, just use the annotation.

Comment: what you mean? hibernate annotations instead gorm?

Comment: @AlaaAbuzaghleh - "not sure why you use the static mapping, just use the annotation.".  That is bad advice.  Why is it that you suggest that?

Comment: your column and domain object naming is complicated. so it seems you are not posting the full code of the domain objects.